# Plural/singular in the following sentences?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Vegans and vegetarians are two different things

This one sounds okay.  But what if i say the same sentence this way

> Vegans and vegetarians are/is not the same things/thing

I think it should be vegans and vegetarians are not the same **things**, because vegans and vegetarians both are plural.

And of there were two singular like:

> Chili and pepper

I guess it should be

> Chili and pepper are not the same thing

Because chili and pepper are singular, so thing should also be singular

Answer (score 2):

One quirk of English is that the singular and plural forms of many words can refer to different things.  For example

> I like **chicken**  (the meat)
>   I like **chickens** (the animals)

In your first example, *vegan* and *vegetarian* (singular) are adjectives used to describe a particular person or diet.

> She maintains a strict **vegetarian** diet

The singular form can also refer to a person who follows the diet, but only if indicated by the context.  Also in this case you usually need some determiner (a, the, this, that, etc.) :

> Susan is a **vegetarian**, so please don't invite her over for "steak night".
>
> I know this **vegan** who is also a body builder.  I don't know how he gets enough protein.

*Vegans* and *vegetarians* (plural) always refer to people who follow that diet.

> Many **vegans** like to do some kind of mindful exercise like yoga.
>
> Although I've never been one,  in my life I've known many **vegetarians**.

It's important to understand what you are talking about when constructing these sentences.  Some options when talking about these as adjectives:

> *Vegan* is not the **same thing** as *vegetarian*.
>
> *Vegan* and *vegetarian* are not the **same thing**.
>
> *Vegan* and *vegetarian* are **different things**.

If talking about these as *people*, you have to write the sentence differently

> A *vegan* is not the **same thing** as a *vegetarian*.
>
> Vegans and vegetarians each have different dietary **restrictions**.

As for your other example, I would probably use quotes (or italicize the words) to make it clear:

> "Chili" and "pepper" are different things.
>
> *Chili* and *pepper* are not the same thing.

Although, actually this is not quite correct.  It would be better to say:

> A "chili" is a kind of "pepper", but not all *peppers* are *chilis*.

Comment: Isn't this correct?  Vegans and vegetarians are not the same things.

Comment: @user236989  Yes, except that it's an awkward sentence because they're not *things*.  They're *people*.   It's usually rude to call a person a thing.  When you say "a vegan" you can imagine you're talking about a *general example*, but "vegans" refers to a group of people.  You can say "Vegans are not the same as vegetarians" though.

Comment: Okay so it was my fault. Let's take another example X and Y is/are not the same thing/things?

Comment: @user236989  Either singular or plural, really.  "Not the same thing" is a kind of *idiomatic phrase*, so few would notice if you used a singular noun to represent plural objects. Ex. *"Chili peppers and bell peppers are not the same **thing**"*.  Grammatically, yes, it makes more sense to say *"Chili peppers and bell peppers are not the same **things**"*  but for some reason it sounds a little odd.  To avoid that I'd just use the singular to represent the general case *"The chili pepper and the bell pepper are not the same **thing**"*.

Comment: But @andew my concern is that chilli pepper and the bell pepper are two things. So shouldn't it be The chili pepper and the bell pepper are not the same *things* not thing

Comment: @user236989  Actually you're trying to say they are not two examples of the same singular object, e.g. *"Batman and Bruce Wayne are the same **person**"* (not **persons**)

Comment: Can we turn this to a chat. Actually I'm quite sceptical about this? I wanna ask few more questions. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65421/discussion-between-user236989-and-andrew).